# Unable to logout from azure AD B2C when Calling Logout action in MVC from Ajax Call

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, azure-ad-b2c

```
$.ajax
({
     async:false,
     cache:false,
     url:"../Account/Singout"
     contentType: "application/json"
     success:function(result){},
     error:function(result){}
});


//MVC Controller code for signout from Azure AD.
public void Signout()
{
    if(Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
                 IEnumerable<AuthenticationDescription> authTypes = 
                  HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetAuthenticationTypes();
                 HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(authTypes.Select(t => 
                 t.AuthenticationType).ToArray());
         }

}
```

/Issue is its not getting signout and redirected to login page. when call via ajax but if call via @Html.ActionLink it is working and getting logged off

Comment: Is there any error message? Is the `Signout` method been triggered?

Comment: simple solution is, use window.location= "../Account/Signout" inside javascript function. This will work. Logout endpoint in B2C doesn't support Ajax requests.

Comment: window.location= "../Account/Signout

Comment: @Ramakrishna ../Account/Signout worked

Answer (score 0):

window.location= "../Account/Signout" Worked for me.

Need to Kmow why Axjax Call does not work when Using AD